# :first-child is not working to select the first h4 element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I was wondering why I can't indent the `:first-child` of `h4`.

All the rest of the `h4` elements should not be indented.

The HTML:

```
<section>
    <article id="5">
        <h2>Top 7 Best Pheromone Colognes for Men (To Attract Women)</h2>
        <h3>2014-01-16</h3>

        <!--img src="https://puaction.com/img/thumb/pua-berlin.jpg" width=80 height=80 title="" alt="" -->

        <h4>What Are Pheromones And Pheromone Colognes? Naturally, pheromones are odorless substances being excreted externally by the fertile body...</h4>
        <h4>What Are Pheromones And Pheromone Colognes? Naturally, pheromones are odorless substances being excreted externally by the fertile body...</h4>
        <h4>What Are Pheromones And Pheromone Colognes? Naturally, pheromones are odorless substances being excreted externally by the fertile body...</h4>
        <h4>What Are Pheromones And Pheromone Colognes? Naturally, pheromones are odorless substances being excreted externally by the fertile body...</h4>
        <h4>What Are Pheromones And Pheromone Colognes? Naturally, pheromones are odorless substances being excreted externally by the fertile body...</h4>
        <h4>What Are Pheromones And Pheromone Colognes? Naturally, pheromones are odorless substances being excreted externally by the fertile body...</h4>
        <h4>What Are Pheromones And Pheromone Colognes? Naturally, pheromones are odorless substances being excreted externally by the fertile body...</h4>

    </article>
</section>
```

The CSS:

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
section article[id] * {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

section article[id] h2 {
    color: #bbb;
}

section article[id] h3 {
    color: #aaa;
}

section article[id] h4 {
    text-align: justify;
}


/* THIS IS NOT WORKING !!! */
section article[id] h4:first-child { /* :first-of-type */
    text-indent: 10px;
}
```

The [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qqsDy/).

Comment: You've commented `first-of-type` already.. than why not use it? `first-child` won't respect what **TYPE** of element you are using

Answer (score 14):

That's because the `<h4>` is not the **first child** of its parent.

[`element:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child) represents the first child of its parent, matching the `element`. And in this particular instance, the first element of `<article>` is a `<h2>` element; Not the `<h4>`.

You could use [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-of-type) pseudo class to select the first `<h4>` element in its parent's children tree, as follows:

```css
section article[id] h4:first-of-type {
    text-indent: 10px;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/qqsDy/5/)**.

From the **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-of-type)**:

> The `:first-of-type` CSS pseudo-class represents the first sibling of
>   its type in the list of children of its parent element.

Comment: Damn!!! I was putting that as a remark (as you can see on my original post) and while I was testing it, It was NOT working !!! WTF !!! but Thanks ! Now it's working (at jsFiddle) and still at my code it's not probably conflict that I need to be solved with !important :) Thanks man !

Answer (score 4):

Try `h4:first-of-type` instead, because the first child of the parent element is not a `<h4>`

Comment: +1 It's also worth checking whether the browsers you are targeting support this selector.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was, in fact, in your fiddle you just didn't use it.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/qqsDy/3/)

```
 /* :first-of-type */
section article[id] h4:first-of-type {
    text-indent: 10px;
}
```