# selecting nested first child element without sibling with css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a chunk of HTML I'm unable to edit (without using JavaScript).

I'm trying to hide a paragraph with CSS. The paragraph doesn't have an `id`. Is there any way to target only it and not its sibling `<p>` with CSS?

HTML:

```
<div id="foo">
     <div></div>
     <p> this is the paragraph to hide</p>
     <p> this one should not be affected</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your markup structure. If the `<p>` is the **first child** of its parent, you can use [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) pseudo-class as follows:

```css
#foo p:first-child { /* or simply #foo :first-child */
    background-color: gold;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/k6y3j/)**

**Note:** If you want to select only the **direct `<p>` child**, you should use the [children selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) (`a > b`) as: `#foo > p:first-child`.

---

But if there are other siblings before the first `<p>` element, you can use CSS3 [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) pseudo-class to select the first `<p>` element in the children tree of its parent:

```css
#foo p:first-of-type {
    background-color: gold;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/k6y3j/1/)**

Again, for the direct child, you can use `#foo > p:first-of-type`.

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type):

> The `:first-of-type` CSS pseudo-class represents the first sibling of
>   its **type** in the list of children of its parent element.

You can refer to **[my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096263/first-child-is-not-working-to-select-the-first-h4-element/22096337#22096337)** for further info.

Comment: I just used `background-color` to highlight the selected element. Obviously you should use `display: none;` to hide the element.

Answer (score 2):

It's the first child of its parent, so you can unambiguously select that:

```
#foo > p:first-child
```