# How to apply style for first heading only if it more than one?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I may have two types of html...

One:

```
<div>
<h4></h4><!--not to this-->
<p></p>
</div>
```

Two:

```
<div>
<h4></h4><!--this should be styled--->
<h4></h4>
<p></p>
</div>
```

All styling are the same but just border-bottom to `h4` of first `h4` tag only if it contains two `h4` tags as in the example. How to do without changing html?

Comment: not possible only in CSS.

Comment: @era sure, but if you change the border-bottom into a border-top you may cheat in some way :)

Comment: @Fabrizio : Very true, though he can use border-top to solve his current problem but this is not the optimized solution. I hope you know the drawbacks :)

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan - did you see my answer, it is actually possible

Comment: @Danield your answer is valid as long you don't add new nodes inside the parent after the first paragraph. Indeed it's working on the specific example but it won't *always* work

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan - I edited my answer to fix that issue, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can combine [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child), [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and [`:only-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-of-type) pseudo-classes to achieve that.

Here you go:

```css
h4:first-child:not(:only-of-type) {
    background-color: gold;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xasaweya/1/edit)**.

This selector represents the `<h4>` element which is the **first child** of its parent whereas it's **not** the only of **TYPE** of elements in the children tree of the parent.

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-of-type):

> The `:only-of-type` CSS pseudo-class represents any element that has
>   no siblings of the given type.

### Let's go *Crazy!*

If the `<h4>` element is not the **first child** of its parent, we can select the first `<h4>` element and achieve the same effect by using [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) pseudo-class as follows:

```css
h4:first-of-type:not(:only-of-type) {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xasaweya/4/edit)**.

For further details on `:first-of-type` vs `:first-child` you can refer [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096263/first-child-is-not-working-to-select-the-first-h4-element/22096337#22096337) here.

Comment: +1 although simply swapping `:first-child` out for `:first-of-type` isn't really going crazy IMO ;)

Comment: @BoltClock haha, yes I think so. I just wanted to make it fun. Please feel free to change that with the proper title :) I'll be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you need to style the `border-bottom` of your 1st `h4` only if the parent contains two adjacent headings

you could then style the `border-top` of the 2nd `h4` and obtain the same effect

```
h4 + h4 {
   border-top: ...
}
```

When you have one heading only, no style will be applied. If you have two or more adjacent headings, a border between them will be applied

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
h4:first-child:nth-last-of-type(n+2)
{
    color:green;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/dLny6/4/)**

Comment: but if you add a paragraph to the first example, the heading is green

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan - what do you mean? I added a paragraph here http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/dLny6/2/   .. and it's not green

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dLny6/3/ on firefox 27 and Chrome I see the first heading green coloured

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan - I edited my answer using nth-last-of-type

Answer (score 0):

You can use the First-child class.

I could look like this:

```
div h4:first-child{
CODE HERE
}
```

Comment: this will apply the style in both the examples

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better off styling the second `h4` if possible, as you would not be able to tell with CSS whether there are one or two `h4`'s in the div.

You can do this with `nth-child`

```
div h4:nth-child(2) {
    // your styles.
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wBnq9/)